# Returning strings in tf.data.Dataset map method

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

In Tensorflow 1.4.1 the map method in tf.data.Dataset could return strings so I could return something like this my map function:

```
return filename, image, one_hot_label
```

where `filename` is string. This doesn't work anymore in TF1.5+:

```
    dataset = dataset.map(self._mapper)

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 838, in map

    return MapDataset(self, map_func)

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1826, in __init__

    self._map_func.add_to_graph(ops.get_default_graph())

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 488, in add_to_graph

    self._create_definition_if_needed()

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 321, in _create_definition_if_needed

    self._create_definition_if_needed_impl()

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 338, in _create_definition_if_needed_impl

    outputs = self._func(*inputs)

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1814, in tf_map_func

    ret, [t.get_shape() for t in nest.flatten(ret)])

      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1814, in <listcomp>

    ret, [t.get_shape() for t in nest.flatten(ret)])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_shape'
```

Is this by design or a regression?

A reproducible example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def map_fn(x):
    return x*2, 'foo'

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
dataset = dataset.map(map_fn)
```

Comment: Are you able to include a reproducible example?

Comment: of course, done

Comment: Can confirm that this also fails in TF 1.6.0. It seems that the string is not converted to a tensor, but I am not sure if this is intended by the devs. A simple workaround: modify the return statement of `map_fn` to `return x*2, tf.convert_to_tensor('foo')`.

Comment: yeah not sure if it's by design or not. Maybe tf data master @mrry can shed some light

Comment: No, this is a bug that was introduced in TF 1.5 (probably as part of adding SparseTensor support). @mikkola's workaround is a good suggestion, but can you open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) so that we remember to add a proper fix?

Comment: FYI I opened an issue here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18355 - @mrry thanks for confirming this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this seems to be a bug in TF 1.5 up to at least 1.6, likely also 1.7. I have opened a Github issue on this at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18355

Until the issue is addressed in a future Tensorflow version, I would suggest to explicitly convert the string output to a tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def map_fn(x):
    # Explicitly convert 'foo' to tensor
    return x*2, tf.convert_to_tensor('foo')

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
dataset = dataset.map(map_fn)
```